# Changing top value by one of 2d array in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

in my code I access a csv sorted as so;

```
0       BrkesGdTiresFair
0       ChessDarts
0       TrainerGeddon
50      EnoughsEnough
100     ShortButFun
101     GrayGlitter
499     PowerAnimal
500     FakeFake
3046    DinosrStlThr
5048    GnrtnlAmnsia
5048    NotEvenWrong
10000   MosquitoSwamp
10048   DrSatansRobot
22042   Kittenszzz
```

and make a 2d array of it;

```
  if(($handle = fopen("voting.csv", 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,',')) !== FALSE) {
          $ListV[$row]=$data;
          $row++;                   
        }
      fclose($handle);
     }
```

I'd like a function that will change the score of the item at the top of the list by 1.
so .....

```
   1    BrkesGdTiresFair
```

I thought this would do it;

```
   $newScore =int($ListV[0][0]);
   $ListV[0][0]=$newScore+1;
```

But it did nothing. I sandboxed this and got a good result;

```
$array = array();

$array[] = array(0, 0, 0, 0);
$array[] = array(5, 5, 5, 5);

$array[0][0]++;

echo $array[0][0]

1
```

So tried this...

```
   $ListV[0][0]++;
```

And just got....

```
0       BrkesGdTiresFair
0       ChessDarts
0       TrainerGeddon
50      EnoughsEnough
100     ShortButFun
101     GrayGlitter
499     PowerAnimal
500     FakeFake
3046    DinosrStlThr
5048    GnrtnlAmnsia
5048    NotEvenWrong
10000   MosquitoSwamp
10048   DrSatansRobot
22042   Kittenszzz
1
```

is it the way I write it?

```
   $listnewV=fopen("ListV.csv",'w');
   foreach ($ListV as $values) {fputcsv($listnewV,$values);}
   fclose ($listnewV);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count   name
0       BrkesGdTiresFair
0       ChessDarts
0       TrainerGeddon
50      EnoughsEnough
100     ShortButFun
101     GrayGlitter
499     PowerAnimal
500     FakeFake
3046    DinosrStlThr
5048    GnrtnlAmnsia
5048    NotEvenWrong
10000   MosquitoSwamp
10048   DrSatansRobot
22042   Kittenszzz


$listV = loadCSV('voting.csv');
$listV[0]['count'] += 1;

$listNewV = fopen("ListV.csv", 'w');
foreach ($ListV as $values) {
    fputcsv($listNewV, $values, "\t");
}
fclose($listNewV);


function loadCSV($file)
{
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "\t");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "\t")) {

        $row_assoc = array();
        foreach ($row as $key => $field) {
            $row_assoc[$header[$key]] = $field;
        }
        $data[] = $row_assoc;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the additional loadCSV help. I've not really got my head around arrays in php, but I'll get there!

Comment: hmmmm, I think the headers make the rest of my code go kablooey, as there is a lot of sorting of the list into other tables I use.


Is there possible a way of doing it without the count and name? I'm a very beginner coder and need to feel my way forward. A very crude solution would work with the rest of my code.